# Using Intersect function gives error code Intersect [175528_07022018]?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersect

I´m doing field selection studies for red deer in ArcGIS. I have several years of data and have made buffer polygons base on the red deer gps positions. The buffer polygons  should be integrated with the field polygons with cultivated crops for each year (to be able to create random positions to represent field availability).

My problem is that the intersect function is not working for some few years and I repeatedly get error messages. Several of the years have been doing fine with the intersect function, but is suddenly not working for some of the years. I have tried so many things to solve it, like subsetting the dataset to make it less heavy (worked for some years), and redoing the buffer polygons, but I cannot get it to work.

I get the error code Intersect [175528_07022018] and I have tried to google it without any hits.

Do anyone have a solution to this problem or know how to interpret the error code?

Comment: Try running Repair Geometry on the feature classes and then Intersect: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please remember to always include the exact version of software in the body of your question,  and to include the complete error message, as text, as well.